# Correct way to create CADisplayLink: UIScreen vs. init()

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, cadisplaylink, uiscreen

There are 2 ways to get CADisplayLink in iOS. The direct one is to use initializer:

```
let displaylink = CADisplayLink(target: self,
                                selector: #selector(step))
```

> Returns a new display link.

This way is used in Apple's example: [Listing 1](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cadisplaylink#2851437).

But there are other way to get it from `UIScreen`:

```
let displayLink = UIScreen.main.displayLink(withTarget: self, 
                                            selector: #selector(step))
```

> Returns a display link object for the current screen.
>   You use display link objects to synchronize your drawing code to the screen’s refresh rate. The newly constructed display link retains the target.

---

Documentation is very poor for details, but the second way looks a little more optimised. May be someone who has experience with `CADisplayLink` can tell which way to create it is preferred.